# The conversion of tstring to string in C++

Tags: c++

This is a snippet of a program which was compiled using visual studio 6. However I'm receiving an error at the following line after compiling in visual studio 2013. I've paste the error statement below.

This is declared in the header File

```
public:
Serial(tstring &commPortName, int bitRate = 115200, char *Name = NULL);
```

This is in the source file

```
string COMport;

    cout << "Enter the COM port (eg. COM1): ";
    cin  >> COMport;

    tstring commPortName(COMport); //**ERROR AT HERE**
    Serial serialDEVICE(commPortName, 115200, "DEVICE");
```

I'm getting the following errors

```
Error   1   error C2664: 
'std::basic_string<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>,std::allocator<wchar_t>>::   
basic_string(std::initializer_list<_Elem>,const std::allocator<wchar_t> &)'  
: cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::string' to 'const
```

The second error:

```
IntelliSense: no instance of constructor "std::basic_string<_Elem, _Traits,    
_Alloc>::basic_string [with _Elem=wchar_t, 
_Traits=std::char_traits<wchar_t>, _Alloc=std::allocator<wchar_t>]" matches
 the argument list argument types are: (std::string)
```

Do i need to do some conversion from tstring to string in order to remove this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`tstring` is not a standard C++ type but I'm going to assume somewhere in your project is something similar to:

```
#ifdef UNICODE
#define tstring std::wstring
#else
#define tstring std::string
#endif
```

In a Unicode build, which Visual Studio defaults to these days, `tstring` is being defined as a `wstring`, meaning it requires a wide string to initialise it. Since `COMPort` is defined as an ANSI string (`std::string`) rather than as a `tstring`, the build fails because the two types are not directly convertible.

You should probably change your project back to an ANSI (multi-byte) build (in the short term at least) as you no doubt will have other compatibility issues without a thorough code review. You can do that using the **Character Set** option in the General section of the Project Properties dialog.

Comment: No, you are correct, tstring is part of the ongoing trainwreck of a maze of string handling functions and macros to try and undo the damage that microsoft caused by not following the C++ programming standards in the first place - presumably because they wanted to "lock-in" code to only compile under microsoft compilers.